# Elasticsearch hunspell cuts words too much

Tags: elasticsearch, hunspell

Consider the following mappings as an example:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_hunspell": {
          "type": "hunspell",
          "language": "en_GB"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_test": {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer": "lowercase",
          "filter": ["my_hunspell"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've downloaded hunspell dictionaries from official Mozilla page.

Now the issue is that some words, for instance beer are over-analyzed. Following query transforms beer into bee, which is not entirely correct?

```
POST /test/_analyze?analyzer=my_test&text=beer

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "bee",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

Hunspell syntax is quite hard to understand. What can be done to avoid such a behaviour? Is it possible preserve some words or to add some rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make it work with coming up with a list of words to preserve, then the [Keyword Marker Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-marker-tokenfilter.html) might be worth looking into.  It looks like that will prevent the words you want to protect from getting stemmed. Your updated analyzer might look something like:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_hunspell": {
          "type": "hunspell",
          "language": "en_GB"
        },
        "protect_my_words": {
          "type": "keyword_marker",
          "keywords_path": <PATH TO TEXT FILE WITH THE WORDS>
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_test": {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer": "lowercase",
          "filter": ["protect_my_words", "my_hunspell"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is also the [Pattern Replace Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) that might prove useful if you do want to transform particular words or patterns.  This can precede the keyword marker token filter.

Comment: I wanted something more dynamic and hunspell related, but keyword token filter does exactly `preserving some keywords`. I'll mark this as correct.